# Virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT is not supported on this platform. Continue without virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am running windows 11 and VMware workstation 16.  I need to do virtualization anyhow to run "Qubes OS".  My pc supports it. I tried all ways of internet even turning off and on hyper v. I am fade up. Please help me. Necessary documents are given. If nested virtualization is possible then the solution will be mind-blowing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what’s your question? How to make VMware Workstation work at full power? Disable Hyper-V then.

Comment: Qubes requires access to virtualisation extensions as well as the host OS. You need to make sure that your CPU supports "nested" VT-x as well as normal, and you need to make sure nested virtualisation is enabled in your VMWare workstation as well.

Comment: @Mokubai my processor supports nested" VT-x as well as normal ,and its enabled in vmware..see pictures

Comment: I am still not clear on what your question is exactly.  If you are running VMWare is there a reason you have Hyper-V installed?

Comment: I turned off hyper v.But yet no solution

Comment: Does *coreinfo* work now? If not, Hyper-V is still active. You need to disable all virtualization-related Windows Features.

Comment: I have disabled all virtualization related feature.Still I am getting this error

Comment: Same issue. Disabled hyper-v and everything to do with hyper-v, restarted and still getting this popup. Enabling/disabling hyper-v involves moving the entire host OS to and from a virtualization layer, so it probably pooped itself while doing that. Windows has become so bloated MS' own native tools corrupt it now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have messed up with Windows Virtual Machine settings that you might mistakenly set or a software you installed changes it.

Last time, we faced this issue after installing the Docker Desktop software which is also a virtualization software

Solution: Turn off Virtual Machine Platform and Hyper-V in Turn Windows Features on or off Settings

Note that if there is a software causes this error, such as Docker Desktop that software might not work because it relies on the above settings.

And you don't need to uninstall either software just switching the 2 above settings on and off for each software is a way around.

Tutorial source: https://mayviti.com/vmware-virtualized-intel-vt-xept-is-not-supported-pc-fixed/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.