# Virtualized Intel VT-x/EPT is not supported on this platform

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, vmware, esxi, esxi5.5

I have installed ESXI 6.5 on PowerEdge 2900 with 8 CPUs x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5420 @ 2.50GHz and 16 GB ram on it but whevever i want to install any other Linux host on it like PNET, EVENG and Kali Linux himself have an error like this when trying to power on it even didn't power on i am totally confused with this i have to enable Intel VT-x to have qemu images running on my VM. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qzC.png)

Comment: Maybe you CPU simply doesn't support nested virtualization (or at least not on vmware products). It's essentially an ancient CPU and doesn't support EPT at all anyway according to Intel ark.

Comment: Technically you CAN use qemu without VT-x, just not KVM.

Comment: @TomYan - The authors CPU definitely supports VT-x. Suspect there is something else going on. Which is difficult to diagnose without system logs

Comment: @Ramhound I said EPT, not VT-x. And I haven't said anything about whether EPT must be relevant, yet either way, there's no strong evidence that (old) CPU that supports (only) VT-x must be universally capable of handling nested virtualization implemented by all hypervisors. (Nevertheless, the error message did at least mention EPT.)

Comment: One thing I do agree is that, perhaps the OP should clarify / confirm whether the VM can start without VT-x/EPT exposed/virtualized first.

Comment: The user is attempting to use nested virtualization within their VM, which isn’t going to be possible on their hardware, I didn’t fully process your original comment. Disabling the option within the configuration of the VM should allow the VM to start[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1669863/virtualized-intel-vt-x-ept-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-continue-without-v)